# How to search for a sub string, and return all values 10 characters to the right of it

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set the variable 'asin' to a 10 alpha-numeric string within the contents of the cell.

The substring being searched will always start with either a B0 or b0. I tried to research a way to make one statement look for either value, but was unable to find this. If anyone can share this it would be greatly appreciated.

The string within the cell being analyzed is: sp - dfns - phrase - B07QMXFJHS - scissors

I believe the issue is with the instr function within the Mid statement.

```
Sub test()
 
Dim asin As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("sp bulkexport")


If InStr(ws.range("d2").Value, "b0") > 0 Then
    asin = Mid(ws.range("d2").Value, InStr(1, ws.range("d2").Value, "b0", 0), 10)
ElseIf InStr(ws.range("d2").Value, "B0") > 0 Then
    asin = Mid(ws.range("d2").Value, InStr(1, ws.range("d2").Value, "B0", 0), 10)
End If


'this is to check the result
ws.range("e3").Value = asin


End Sub
```

Comment: `v = ws.range("d2").Value: pos = Instr(UCase(v), "B0")` will handle both cases.  Then test with `If pos > 0 Then asin = Mid(v, pos, 10)`

Comment: A guideline which you can use to improve your coding experience is "don't repeat yourself" If you find yourself typing (eg) `Range("d2").Value` more than once (or 6 times) then use a variable to capture that value instead.  Now if the range changes you only have one place to change your code. Less worksheet access also improves your code performance.

Comment: ...or change your 3rd argument to Instr to 1 ("text compare") instead of 0 ("binary compare")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might encode your idea as shown below.

```
Dim Ws      As Worksheet
Dim Asin    As String
Dim n       As Long                 ' used by Instr()

Set Ws = Worksheets("sp bulkexport")
With Ws.Cells(2, "D")
    n = InStr(1, .Value, "b0", vbTextCompare)
    If n Then Asin = Mid(.Value, n, 10)
    
    'this is to check the result
    Offset(1, 1).Value = UCase(Asin)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well. Just curious, would you be willing to write this without the 'with' statement? Although it works, the 'with' statement is preventing me from seeing exactly how it is working... I am still unfamiliar with the 'with' statement, and it is throwing me off.  thanks again.

Comment: Wherever you see a leading `.` replace it with  `Ws.Cells(2, "D").`